# $f\in BV[a,b]$ has the intermediate value property , then is it true that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, bounded-variation

If $f\in BV[a,b]$ has the intermediate value property , then is it true that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ ?  Please help . Thanks in advacne

Comment: a function with bounded variation has jump discontinuities only

Comment: Having the intermediate value property is ofter called being a [Darboux function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function). Together with the previous comment this should help you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1. $f\in BV[a,b]$ is a difference of two (non-strictly) increasing functions.
2. $f(a+)$, $f(b-)$, and $f(x\pm)$ exist in $\mathbb R$ for every $x\in (a,b)$.
3. Assume $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $x\in(a,b)$. Could $f$ have the intermediate value property?